# Unable to use a value of type DAGNetwork as an index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

I have build the UNET model in MATLAB, the training was interrupted, Now I am trying to resume/continue the training from the last checkpoint (saved during the training) , but I got the Error

" Unable to use a value of type DAGNetwork as an index.

Error in (line 31)  training = trainNetwork(pximds,lgraph(net),options); "

Here is my code, can someone tell me why I got this error.

```
1- clear all
2- close all
3- load('net_checkpoint__226644__2021_07_08__16_18_25.mat','net') 

4-    matlabpath = 'E:\My project';
5- data = fullfile(matlabpath,'ImageDatasetforPixelLabelDataSeries6-     
6-   21');
7-  data1 = fullfile(matlabpath,'PixelLabelDataSeries6-21');
8-  imds = imageDatastore(data,'IncludeSubfolders',true,
9-  'LabelSource','foldernames'); 
10-  classes = ["CatheterMarkerVessel" "Background"];
11-  pixelLabelIDs = [0 1];
12-  pxds = pixelLabelDatastore(data1, classes ,pixelLabelIDs);
13-  trainingdata = pixelLabelImageSource(imds,pxds);
14-  tbl = countEachLabel(trainingdata);

15-  imageSize = [1024 1024 1];
16-  numClasses = numel(classes);

17-  lgraph = unetLayers(imageSize,numClasses,'EncoderDepth',5); 
 
18-  %% Data Augmentation
19-  augmenter = imageDataAugmenter('RandXReflection',true,
20-  'RandYReflection',true);
21-   pximds = pixelLabelImageDatastore(imds,pxds,'DataAugmentation', 
22-   augmenter);
 
23-  %% Training
24-  options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
25-  'InitialLearnRate',0.0001, ...
26-  'Momentum',0.99, ...
27-  'MiniBatchSize',1, ... 
28-  'MaxEpochs',300, ...
29-  'Plots','training-progress', ...
30-  'CheckpointPath','E:\My Project'); 


31-  training = trainNetwork(pximds,lgraph(net),options);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try and make the code snippets you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can better help you with your problem. Given your post now, it's not clear what line of code caused the error and where `DAGNetwork` came from.

Comment: Hello user3667217, 
Thanks for your reply, I have edited the post, can you please have a look. I have mentioned the line number which caused the error i.e. line 31. Please help me to get rid of this error and help me to successfully continue the training from last check point.

Thank you.